# Netsuite - Saved Search Formula(text) Case statement concat 2 fields

Tags: netsuite

I need to concat 2 fields Order (Number and Ship method) with formula(text), I have this formula,

CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT('', {number}), CONCAT('', {custcol_rb_ship_method})), {linesequencenumber}).

As order number is
name: "formulatext_ordernumber",
formula: "CONCAT({number}, CONCAT('_' ,{linesequencenumber}))" //order number
{custcol_rb_ship_method} // ship method

However, I need a better solution with the case statement or if/else statement? Can anyone suggest something or help, please?

For example, for order PO-RBL-05964-1 and shipping method - Sea, the final order number will look like PO-RBL-05964-1 (Sea)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netsuite you may use the `||` to concatenate the values.

eg. `CASE WHEN {custcol_rb_ship_method} != ' ' THEN ( {linesequencenumber} || ' (' || custcol_rb_ship_method || ')') ELSE 'NULL or whatever' END`

Comment: HI, Thank you very much for the answer I have amended a little bit the formula and it is worked perfect. Here is the solution that I have done and works as it should! CASE WHEN {custcol_rb_ship_method} != ' ' THEN ( {number} || ' (' || {custcol_rb_ship_method} || ')') ELSE 'NULL' END